# How do I connect NLB to VPC endpoints for Private API GW in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I have added a TCP listener to my NLB and this listener forwards the traffic to the target group containing IP addressees (TCP targets). These IP addressees are of VPC endpoints (private API GW).

This setup is not working for me. The NLB can't connect to the endpoints. Is this possible in first place? I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. I couldn't find any documentation on it. The resource policy and the security group on the VPC endpoint is allow-everything.

I am running the following curl command on the NLB.

`curl -k -X POST https://example-xxxxxxxxxx.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mystage/test -H'x-apigw-api-id:xxxxxxxxxx' -v`

Comment: You need to provide full details of your setup. NLB? SGs? Endpoints? Do the endpoints even work without NLB or nothing works?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint works. If I replace the above hostname (example-xxx....) with the IP address (private IP) of the VPC endpoint and run the command from an ec2 instance, I get a response from the private API GW (backed by lambda)